# $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^z - e^{-\frac{\pi ki}{n}}} \, dz$

Tags: integration, limits

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^z - e^{-\frac{\pi ki}{n}}} \, dz$$

Initially I address one integral where I replace $\exp(−πki/n)$
with some complex constant  α
such that the integrand stays integrable in order to be able to generalize results, but that ended very dirty things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antiderivative being simple, you face the problem of computing
$$S_n=-\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} e^{\frac{i \pi  k}{n}} \log
   \left(1-e^{-\frac{i \pi  k}{n}}\right)$$ Not very helful, the summand can write
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)+i \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)\right) \left(\log \left(2-2 \cos
   \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)\right)+2 i \arg
   \left(1-e^{-\frac{i \pi  k}{n}}\right)\right)$$

I do not know if there could be a closed form for $S_n$ but you could compare to the result of the continuous case
$$T_n=-\int _{1}^{n-1} e^{\frac{i \pi  k}{n}} \log
   \left(1-e^{-\frac{i \pi  k}{n}}\right)\,dk$$
$$T_n=n-2-i\frac {n}\pi\left(\left(1+e^{-\frac{i \pi }{n}}\right) \log \left(1+e^{\frac{i
   \pi }{n}}\right)-  \left(1-e^{\frac{i \pi }{n}}\right) \log \left(1-e^{-\frac{i
   \pi }{n}}\right)   \right)$$ which, expanded for large values of $n$ is

$$T_n= \left(n-\log (n)+\log \left(\frac{\pi }{2 e}\right)\right)-i\,\frac{ \left(4 n \log (2)-\pi ^2\right)}{2 \pi }+\cdots$$